# Proving bijectivity of $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,2)$, where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+1$ for $x>1$, and $f(x)=x$ for $x\le 1$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

> Let $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0,2)$ be defined by $$f(x) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       \frac{1}{x} + 1, & x > 1 \\
>       x, & x\le 1 \\
> \end{array} 
> \right.$$
>
> The question asks to prove that the function is bijective.

I have to prove it is injective and surjective.

Injectivity:
if $x,y<1$, then $x=y$
if $x,y>1$ then, $\frac{1}{x}+1=\frac{1}{y}+1$, then $x=y$

> I get this bit, but I don't get how to prove the surjective part of the proof.

Please could you help?

Comment: For injective: you will also need to rule out $x\le 1, y > 1$ and $x = \frac{1}{y}+1$.  Hint to help your solution: draw the graph of $f$.

Comment: Surjectivity says that for all $y\in [0,2)$, there is some $x\in [0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)=y$. You're trying to solve for the value of $x$ that gives you $y$. You should address this in two cases: what if $y>1$, and what if $y\leq 1$. The first case should be easy, the second should be a little more complicated, but not hard.

Comment: "Injectivity: if x<1 then x=y"  Not necessarily.  Maybe $x = \frac 1y + 1$....."if x>1 then $(\frac 1x)+1=(\frac1y)+1$.  Not necessarily.  Maybe $\frac 1x + 1 = y$.....  Nitpick:  You never actually *stated* that $f(x) = f(y)$.  Without *stating* that $x$ and $y$ can be anything and have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f_1(x)=x$$ for $$x\in [0,1]$$
and
$$f_2(x)=\frac 1x +1$$ for $$x>1$$

$f_1$ is a bijection from $[0,1] $ to $[0,1]$ and $ f_2$ is a bijection from $(1,+\infty)$ to $ (1,2)$. thus $f$ is a bijection from $[0,1]\cup (1,\infty)$ to $[0,1]\cup (1,2)$.

Other proof.

Let $ y\in[0,2)$. We will prove it has only one antecedent.

If $y\in[0,1]$ then $f(y)=y$.
the antecedent is unique in $[0,1]$

if $y\in(1,2)$ then $f(\frac{1}{y-1})=y$ with $\frac{1}{y-1}>1$.
the antecedent is unique in $(1,\infty)$

Comment: First proof stands only since the domains and codomains of $f_1,f_2$ are disjoint. You should have point this out.

Comment: @user26857 Yes you are right. but in our case, they are( obvious). thanks .

Answer (score -1):

Injectivity:  Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$.

There are four cases:  $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0\le y \le 1$ and $f(x) = x = f(y) = y$.  Thus $x = y$.

$0 \le x \le 1$ and $y > 1$ and $f(x) = x = f(y) = \frac 1y +1$.  So $x = \frac 1y + 1$. And $y= \frac 1{x-1}$.  But if $y > 1$ then $0 < \frac 1y < 1$ and $1 < \frac 1y + 1< 2$ which contradicts $0\le x \le 1$.  (Likewise $0\le x=\frac 1y + 1 \le 1\implies -1 \le \frac 1y \le 0\implies y < 0$ also a contradiction).

$x> 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$.  .... also gives a contradiction...  Too similar to the above to bear discussing.

[Note: we could have avoided these contradictory options by noting that $0\le w \le 1 \implies 0\le w=f(w) \le 1$ and $w > 1 \implies 0<\frac 1w < 1\implies 1 < \frac 1w + 1 = f(w) < 2$.  So $f(w) \in [0,1] \iff w \in [0,1]$ and $f(w) \in (1,2) \iff w\in (0,1)$.]

Fourth and final case $x > 1$ and $y > 1$.  Then $\frac 1x + 1 = \frac 1y + 1$ so $\frac 1x = \frac 1y$ so $x=y$.

So $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$.

Surjectivity:

Let $k \in [0, 2)$.  If $1 < k < 2$ and if $2>\frac 1x + 1 = k >1$ then $1> \frac 1x = k- 1 > 0$ and $x =\frac 1{k-1} > 1$.

So if $1 < k < 2$ then $\frac 1{k-1} >1$ so $f(\frac 1{k-1}) = k$.

If if $0\le k \le 1$ then $f(k) = k$.

Either way for all $k\in [0,\infty)$ there is $x$ either equal to $k$ if $k \le 1$ or equal to $\frac 1{k-1}$ if $k > 1$  so that $f(x) = k$.